# What is the fastest way to find an integer in an array?

Tags: arrays, data-structures

**Problem:** Given a userID (integer) quickly find which group the user belongs to. Groups will contain no more than 15 users. Additionally, I am using libev which gives me no control over the parameters passed into the read I/O event, so the userID (file descriptor/integer) is really the *only* thing I can use.

**My solution:** hash once on the userID into a hash table containing groupID and userID pairs. Hash a second time on the groupID to a hash table containing groupID and array of 15 userID pairs.

The solution works, but this is server code that will be executed an ungodly amount of times. I wonder if the double hashing will be inefficient and if there may be a better solution.

Comment: Posting the actual code you're using on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ might be a better idea.

Comment: Not sure why someone changed the title of the post to a different question than what I am asking.

Answer (score 2):

You say that libev only gives you a limited amount of data—the `ev_io` handle itself—and conclude that all there is useful in there is the file descriptor. Well, normally, you're probably right, but there's a neat trick you can do.

Since with libev, you allocate the structures yourself and then have libev initialize them, there's nothing stopping you from allocating *too much* space. Since libev won't be touching that extra space, you can put your own stuff in there. Success!

So how does this work in practice? You create a new structure containing an `ev_io` as the first member, and then put all the rest of your data after it, say like this:

```
struct my_mutant_io {
    ev_io handle;
    int group_id;
};
```

Now, wherever you allocate a `uv_io`, allocate a `my_mutant_io` instead. Put your data in there however you'd like and once you need to pass it to a libuv function, just take the address of `handle` instead:

```
struct my_mutant_io *mutant = malloc(sizeof(struct my_mutant_io));
if(!mutant) {
    abort();
}
mutant->group_id = /* ... */;
ev_io_init(&mutant, some_callback, fd, EV_READ);
```

You've given libev a `ev_io`, and it's none-the-wiser that it's actually just a part of a larger struct. Now let's move on to the callback. You'll get your `ev_io` back, but wait! Since the `ev_io` is the first member of the struct, its address is the same as the address of our mutant. We can cast the `ev_io *` right back to a `struct my_mutant_io *` and use it. (Just don't tell the strict-aliasing gods.)

A struct like this is most commonly called a baton.